# Unable to access component through routing when not debugging

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I am currently developing a Angular Single Page Application with A Dot Net Core API backend, and I am experiencing an issue with the routing in my application.

When using 'ng-serve' in my Angular application and access the SPA using localhost:4200, I can access my password reset route and the component shows.
However when I run the 'ng-build' to create the wwwroot folder in my Dot Net Core API and try to access the route through the address bar it says the page cannot be found, neither in localhost:38611 or localhost:44316 (SSL).

The code for my navigation-route is below

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'password-reset', component: UserPasswordResetComponent },
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 {
  path: '',
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  canActivate: [AuthenticateGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'downloads', component: MenuDownloadsComponent },
    { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent }
  ]
 },
 {
  path: '',
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  canActivate: [ManagerGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'manager-dashboard', component: DashboardManagerComponent },
    { path: 'history', component: MenuHistoryComponent }
  ]
 },
 {
   path: '',
   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
   canActivate: [AdminGuard],
   children: [
    { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: DashboardAdminComponent },
    { path: 'user-admin', component: MenuAdminUserComponent },
    { path: 'company-admin', component: MenuAdminCompanyComponent },
    { path: 'software-admin', component: MenuAdminSoftwareComponent },
    { path: 'release-admin', component: MenuAdminReleaseComponent },
    { path: 'item-admin', component: MenuAdminItemComponent },
    { path: 'uploads', component: MenuUploadsComponent }
   ]
 },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I am confused to why it works in one instance but not the others, any help would be much appreciated.

I use VS Code for my Angular (which I have recently updated to Angular 10) and Visual Studio for the Dot Net Core (which is version 3.1) but I have also tried running it in VS Code to no avail.